# the meaning of would

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning of **would** in this sentence:

> *Guy Fawkes established a reputation as a soldier of great courage, a fact that would lead to his participation in the infamous Gunpowder Plot.*

Comment: It's taking you to a point in time when his reputation has been established, but he has not yet participated in the gunpowder plot. It is is saying that that lay in the future and implying that it had not been foreseen, like *which, as it transpired, led to his participation...*.

Answer (score 1):

"Would" is the past tense of the verb **"will"**, that refers to something happening in future.

His participation in the gunpowder plot happened in the future of him establishing a reputation as a soldier, hence the use of "will", but as that was in past as compared to today (or whenever this text was written), the past form of "will" is used.

Comment: Is it future would or modal would?

Comment: @Fatimahon future

Comment: And if we accept that there is no future tense in English?

Comment: @Fatimahon but there is

Comment: And according to the two tense system of the English verb there is not. The main question is what other meaning besides future meaning the verb would gas in this sentences opposed to the same verb in the past ( led ).

Comment: @Fatimahon Your question about there being no future tense is essentially of no practical value. Even if you accept that theory (which many people don't), it's just semantics. It is still used *as if* there is a future tense, and it's still understood to communicate the same idea.

Comment: I dare say it is, as there is some difference between would lead and led in semantics, and it is interesting for me what this difference is, as I am not a native speaker.